# Firebase anonymous auth is triggering both sides of a JS if statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have followed the Google reference documents but find that the firebase auth triggers both sides of the if statement.

```
calcbtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
//Auth
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(`${errorCode}: ${errorMessage}`);
    // ...
});
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      uid = user.uid;
      console.log(`UserID: ${uid}`);
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      console.log('Error: User is not authenticated');
      // ...
    }
    // ...
});
```

Returns both the userID and the Error: User is not authenticated?

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` is a listener which will get called whenever user logs in or user signs out

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad, I understand that, I just don't understand why both sides of the if  (user) statement are fired?  This is per the docs but the behaviour does not seem to be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially when you attach the `onAuthStateChanged`, no user will be signed in yet. So at that point your callback will be called with `null`.

Then the user sign in triggered by `signInAnonymously()` completes and another call is made to your callback with that `user` object.

This is normal operation for an auth state listener in Firebase: it will usually initially be called with `null`, and then with the actual user object.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your reply.  It does make sense other than the fact that the else statement is triggered - how do I stop that triggering until the object is returned and so the code can run correctly?

Comment: You can't change the behavior of the API, so you will have to deal with its behavior in your code. It is unclear from your question what problem you are trying to address, so I'm not sure how to change your code (otherwise I would have already included that in my answer).

Comment: Hi Frank, I want to use the if statement to warn that the user is signed out and needs to log in - but he may already be logged in?

Comment: Yeah, that's a common scenario. The problem is that `onAuthStateChange` won't fire with the user until it has restored the state, so the initial `null` value may mean "not signed in, never signed in" and "signed in before, checking state". To detect the difference between the latter two, you can store a marker in local storage. See for an explanation of this: https://youtu.be/NwY6jkohseg?t=1309

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you, that is a really interesting video.